# Is mobile browser geolocation as good as native?

Tags: ios, html, geolocation, location, google-play-services

When you open a webpage on a phone/tablet, and use

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

Do we get the same results that when we use Google Play services location API?

And do we get the same results that when we use iOS native location API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is really depends to what level of information is available in both OS.

For example, if both GPS chip is working in both Android and iOS and locked to the right numbers of satellite, then you should get the same results.

However, when GPS is not available, each API uses their own way such as wifi, cell tower ID or IP address to estimate the location, then you will find some discrepancy.

Reference: http://www.geolocation.com